# Recyclerlistview error : "Cannot call a class as a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Can anyone help me?
I have this problem in React Native :(
Recyclerlistview error : "Cannot call a class as a function"
https://snack.expo.dev/@mmdrezaaramideh/courageous-truffle

I tried every way I could think of.do You have a suggestion?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here line 40, replace:

```js
dim.width = Dimensions('window').width;
```

with

```js
dim.width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```